# This iterator is not iterating, whats wrong?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Problem is that the iterator is not iterating through the loop. I don't know why. #includes are in the header as is my wont.

```
#include "neutronFileReader.h"

using namespace std ;

neutronFileReader::neutronFileReader()
{
}

list<vector<float> > neutronFileReader::spectrum(char* filename)
{
    ifstream fin(filename) ;
    string binhi, binlo ;
    list<vector<float> > neutronSpectrum ;
    list<vector<float> >::iterator nS ;
    vector<float> EnergyProbability ;

    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, binlo, ' ') ;                        //get the binlo string
        cout << "binlo: "<<binlo << endl ;
        getline(fin, binhi, ' ') ;                        //get the binhi string
        cout<<"binhi: "<<binhi<<endl ;
        EnergyProbability.push_back(atof(binhi.c_str())+(atof(binhi.c_str()) - atof(binlo.c_str()))/2) ;    //store middle of bin as emission Energy
        getline(fin, binlo) ;                            //try not to waste memory space
        cout<<"prob: "<<binlo<<endl ;
        EnergyProbability.push_back(atof(binlo.c_str())) ;    //store emnission probability
        neutronSpectrum.push_back(EnergyProbability) ;    //put the vector in the list
        //cout<<neutronSpectrum<<endl ;
    }


    for(nS = neutronSpectrum.begin() ; nS != neutronSpectrum.end() ; nS++)  //go through the neutron spectrum
    {
        EnergyProbability = (*nS) ;
        cout << "binval: " << EnergyProbability[0] << " " << "binProb: " << EnergyProbability[1] << endl ;
        cout << "binval: " << (*nS)[0] << ", binprob: " << (*nS)[1] << ", memadd: " << &nS << endl ;          // print energy & prob to screen
    }

    return neutronSpectrum ;
}
```

anyway, some help here would be greatly appreciated, have moved it into a while loop, yes this is all bug testing but it's a fairly important bit of code. Cheers guys, always learning.

Comment: Did you try to print out the size of your list first? Just to make sure you actually have a list to iterate through :)

Comment: whats the problem, does it not compile ? does it crash?. Describe the situation a bit more for other to help you .

Comment: What makes you think it isn't iterating?

Comment: You'll notice the EnergyProbability vector isn't being cleared between loops on the input... say the first loop pushes a new vector with `[value1, value2]`, then the second loop pushes `[value1, value2, value3, value4]`.  The final iteration goes through printing the `[value1, value2]` entries from each vector, not noticing the newever values in subsequent indices.

Comment: @Tony you are correct, thats what was happening, however it still wont exit the loop and the pointer output (&nS) is always printing the same memory address. The loop never exits as it is still pointing at the first element but IS outputting the expected output of individual list AND vector elements ( (*nS)[0] ). This makes no sense to me, unless &nS is pointing automatically to the beginning of the list, outputting that address, and retaining the actual pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing out EnergyProbability between input loops.  (*ns)[0] is therefore seeing the redundantly stored values from the first input, ignoring the new values which are actually in [2], then [4] etc..  Just add `EnergyProbability.clear()` before reading more values into it.

Comment: Better yet, scope the variable properly, so that it gets automatically re-constructed each time through the loop. Clean, correct code first, before worrying about optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are populating the `neutronSpectrum` array, so it's not empty? Please make sure by adding this to the end:

```
if (neutronSpectrum.empty())
  cerr << "error: empty neutronSpectrum" << endl;
```

Maybe there is a problem with your input file (it's empty or unreadable), so you end up adding nothing to `neutronSpectrum` in the first place. Just to make sure, please add some `cout` statements to your `while` loop. Also it's worth checking for `fin.error()` after the `while` loop:

```
if (fin.error())
  cerr << "error: error reading input file: " filename << endl;
```

Comment: If the list were empty would list.begin() and list.end() not be equal? Then the for would exit on zero iterations. Checked for list not being populated earlier, is populated, only the first element is being pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing gets printed in the `for`-loop at the end `neutronSpectrum` is probably empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, have checked all the above, one issue was that I was not clearing the EnergyProbability vector each iteration of the while loop (not that it was empty), this was creating a larger and larger vector which was pushed to the back of the list each time, so the first two elements of the pointed to list element (A vector) were being output, and these were the same each time (obviously, I am a fool). So, now I know the issue is in fact that the iterator is not recognising that it has reache the end of the list, and when it doees it is throwing a null pointer, I think. code here:

```
#include "neutronFileReader.h"

using namespace std ;

neutronFileReader::neutronFileReader()
{
}

list<vector<float> > neutronFileReader::spectrum(char* filename)
{
ifstream fin(filename) ;
string binhi, binlo ;
list<vector<float> > neutronSpectrum ;
list<vector<float> >::iterator nS ;
vector<float> EnergyProbability ;

while(!fin.eof())
{
    EnergyProbability.clear() ;
    getline(fin, binlo, ' ') ;                      //get the binlo string
    cout << "binlo: "<<binlo << endl ;
    getline(fin, binhi, ' ') ;                      //get the binhi string
    cout<<"binhi: "<<binhi<<endl ;
    EnergyProbability.push_back(atof(binhi.c_str())+(atof(binhi.c_str()) - atof(binlo.c_str()))/2) ;    //store middle of bin as emission Energy
    getline(fin, binlo) ;                           //try not to waste memory space
    cout<<"prob: "<<binlo<<endl ;
    EnergyProbability.push_back(atof(binlo.c_str())) ;  //store emnission probability
    cout << EnergyProbability[0] << ":" << EnergyProbability[1] << endl ;
    neutronSpectrum.push_back(EnergyProbability) ;  //put the vector in the list
}

for(nS = neutronSpectrum.begin() ; nS != neutronSpectrum.end() ; nS++)  //go through the neutron spectrum
{
    EnergyProbability = (*nS) ;
    cout << &neutronSpectrum.begin() << " : " << &nS << " : " << &neutronSpectrum.end() << endl ;         // print energy & prob to screen
}


return neutronSpectrum ;
}
```

output is:

```
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8  
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8 
0x28fbcc : 0x28fba8 : 0x28fbc8
```

then code::blocks must realise it is in an infinite loop where nothing is changing and quits the code.

cheers guys

Comment: oh, ignore the pop that was to see if the loop only had one entry, redundant now and removed.

Comment: ok, so i am outputting the address of the pointer, not the address pointed to, sorry people.